# Can't see Wi-Fi settings in Ubuntu 20.04 LTS

Tags: networking, dual-boot, 20.04, intel, iwlwifi

I am new to Ubuntu and until yesterday all was working fine but when I booted Ubuntu today I can't see the WiFi options in my tray or in the settings.

[image]

I have tried restarting the network manager using
 `sudo network-manager restart`
but there isn't any change.

I also tried
`lshw -c network`
and  I get the following results

```
WARNING: you should run this program as super-user.

  *-network UNCLAIMED
       description: Network controller
       product: Wireless-AC 9260
       vendor: Intel Corporation
       physical id: 0
       bus info: pci@0000:3d:00.0
       version: 29
       width: 64 bits
       clock: 33MHz
       capabilities: bus_master cap_list
       configuration: latency=0
       resources: iomemory:ffffffff0-fffffffef memory:ed200000-ed203fff
```

Also running
`sudo modprobe iwlwifi && dmesg | grep iwlwifi`
gives me this error

```
[   21.148797] iwlwifi 0000:3d:00.0: enabling device (0000 -> 0002)
[   21.526168] iwlwifi: probe of 0000:3d:00.0 failed with error -110
```

PC Specs:

Intel i7-9750H

Nvidia RTX 2070 MaxQ

16 GB 2666 DDR4 RAM

1TB HDD + 256GB SSD

Dual boot Ubuntu 20.04LTS and Windows 10

Thanks

Comment: Disavle Windows Fast Start feature.

Comment: @Pilot6 Windows Fast Start and Secure boot were disabled when I was installing Ubuntu.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are using a Dual Boot PC and this occurs after you have just restarted into Ubuntu after booting from Windows. Shutdown PC, boot into window and use shutdown and boot again into Ubuntu instead of Restart as the state of the Wi-Fi Device may not change since windows disabled it for restarting

As for me after contacting Dell a service engineer came to visit me and the problem seems to be a broken antenna cable (this seems to be a common problem with Intel Killer WiFi cards) which connects to the WiFi card. Replacing this would fix the problem in my case.

Thanks for the Help.

Answer (score 1):

I got the same issue today when I turned on my PC. My WiFi driver was unavailable in the ‘Additional drivers’ section of ‘Software & Updates’.  I tried and checked if this would fix with restarting the PC. But it didn’t.

So, I connected my PC through wired connection and updated Ubuntu through ‘Software Updater’. After that I restarted my PC and now it is working fine.

Comment: Tired this running updates were my first go-to solution, but it didn't work for me

Comment: You might have tried this, if not, go to settings, search for WiFi in the settings, if it’s saying driver not found then open ‘Additional drivers’ and check if it is using any WiFi driver there.

Comment: Can't find WiFi in settings.

Comment: Sorry. I think I’m not able to help you. Someone who knows better must check this issue and can help you.